# What kind of Rails app would not be possible on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, deployment, heroku

I've tried Heroku not long time ago and is a fantastic platform.
Since I want to use it for ALL kind of wep applications I have in mind now and that I will have to do in the future, what kind of application is *not* possible to host on Heroku, if there is any?
What alternative you suggest for that applications?

Comment: Stack Overflow. It's too epic for Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a question of whether you could host on Heroku or not, but which particular things you can do on Heroku, and which things you need alternative (often better) solutions for.

For instance, you can't save to the filesystem on Heroku itself, so any file or image uploads need to be saved to an external source (such as Amazon S3).

See http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-constraints for more.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now Heroku only hosts Ruby Apps, Node.js, And Clojure so anything done with these languages Heroku can handle.

In terms of scaling Heroku might not be the best choice for applications that get ton's of traffic. It's funny that Engine Yard has the slogan 'When apps grow up' and this is kinda the start with Heroku for free, and if you app gets traffic then move to something that might be better for performance.

That said, for truly large websites all of the ruby hosts are probably not the way to go which is currently using passenger with multiple servers.